# why I see this when compiling my project in bootstrap? "Found 0 JPA repository interfaces."

Tags: java, spring, controller, swagger

I have created a Bootstrap project in which I have 3 repositories. When I compile the project I do not receive any errors but unfortunately I can not see my controllers in Swagger!!!
I have found out that line 4 says:

> Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 4 ms. Found 0 JPA
> repository interfaces.

I think this the reason that I can not see the controllers. Any idea to solve this? Thank you in advance.

```
2021-12-14 00:26:13.768  INFO 5472 --- [           main] WBSthesis.rotab.RotabApplication     

    : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2021-12-14 00:26:14.648  INFO 5472 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Bootstrapping Spring Data JPA repositories in DEFAULT mode.
2021-12-14 00:26:14.661  INFO 5472 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : ***Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 4 ms. Found 0 JPA repository interfaces.***
2021-12-14 00:26:15.592  INFO 5472 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)
2021-12-14 00:26:15.609  INFO 5472 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2021-12-14 00:26:15.609  INFO 5472 --- [           main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.54]
2021-12-14 00:26:15.718  INFO 5472 --- [           main] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2021-12-14 00:26:15.718  INFO 5472 --- [           main] w.s.c.ServletWebServerApplicationContext : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 1885 ms
2021-12-14 00:26:15.975  INFO 5472 --- [           main] o.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper  : HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [name: default]
2021-12-14 00:26:16.051  INFO 5472 --- [           main] org.hibernate.Version                    : HHH000412: Hibernate ORM core version 5.4.32.Final
2021-12-14 00:26:16.226  INFO 5472 --- [           main] o.hibernate.annotations.common.Version   : HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.1.2.Final}
2021-12-14 00:26:16.356  INFO 5472 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Starting...
2021-12-14 00:26:16.562  INFO 5472 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Start completed.
2021-12-14 00:26:16.580  INFO 5472 --- [           main] org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect            : HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL55Dialect
2021-12-14 00:26:16.856  INFO 5472 --- [           main] o.h.e.t.j.p.i.JtaPlatformInitiator       : HHH000490: Using JtaPlatform implementation: [org.hibernate.engine.transaction.jta.platform.internal.NoJtaPlatform]
2021-12-14 00:26:16.866  INFO 5472 --- [           main] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Initialized JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2021-12-14 00:26:17.090  WARN 5472 --- [           main] JpaBaseConfiguration$JpaWebConfiguration : spring.jpa.open-in-view is enabled by default. Therefore, database queries may be performed during view rendering. Explicitly configure spring.jpa.open-in-view to disable this warning
2021-12-14 00:26:17.225  INFO 5472 --- [           main] pertySourcedRequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped URL path [/v2/api-docs] onto method [springfox.documentation.swagger2.web.Swagger2Controller#getDocumentation(String, HttpServletRequest)]
2021-12-14 00:26:17.490  INFO 5472 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat started on port(s): 8080 (http) with context path ''
2021-12-14 00:26:17.491  INFO 5472 --- [           main] d.s.w.p.DocumentationPluginsBootstrapper : Context refreshed
2021-12-14 00:26:17.511  INFO 5472 --- [           main] d.s.w.p.DocumentationPluginsBootstrapper : Found 1 custom documentation plugin(s)
2021-12-14 00:26:17.544  INFO 5472 --- [           main] s.d.s.w.s.ApiListingReferenceScanner     : Scanning for api listing references
2021-12-14 00:26:17.698  INFO 5472 --- [           main] WBSthesis.rotab.RotabApplication         : Started RotabApplication in 4.468 seconds (JVM running for 4.958)
```

Answer (score 1):

If your Spring Boot project folder name contains a space and/or your project path contains a space, Spring Data JPA may not be able to find your repository interfaces.

For example, if your project is under a folder named `/My Project` and your project path is `User/username/Project/My Project/myproject`, Spring Data JPA may not find your repository interfaces and produce the "Found 0 JPA repository interfaces" message.

To avoid this issue, you should avoid using spaces in your project folder names or project paths. Instead, use hyphens or underscores to separate words in folder names and project paths.

Answer (score 0):

More info of your project would be helpful, but maybe your interfaces are not inside the right package. I was facing this once...

**Here is an example.**

[image]

**Notice that all sub-packages are on the same level as the @SpringBootApplication.**